# Which HTTP headers match certain methods?

Tags: database, http, web, http-headers

I want to make a database where I store data from HAR files. Specifically, I want, by European standards, to store the following headers from HTTP requests and responses.

- content-type
- cache-control
- pragma
- expires
- age
- last-modified
- host

In order to make an efficient MySQL database though, I need to categorise them in a way where I get the least amount of empty columns. Problem is, that I cannot find any information about which types of request/responses get specific headers.

The idea is to make different ISA tables for request and headers where I include the headers that will definitely be included in the corresponding request/response.

I think it might have to do with the method of the request, but I have not found ANY info about that online

Answer (score 0):

In general, header fields are not specific to methods; more likely to the distintion between request and response, status code, and whether a payload is present in the request.

(The details are in RFCs 7230..5).